# Difference between f(a,b) and f(a)(b) in Scala

Tags: scala

I am very very new to Scala. I am reading a book called functional programming in scala by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason. So far I am finding it interesting. I see a solution for curry and uncurry

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C)= {
    a => b => f(a,b)
  }

def uncurry[A,B,C](f: A => B => C): (A, B) => C = {
    (a,b) => f(a)(b)
  }
```

In Curry I understand f(a,b) which results in value of type C but in uncurry I do not understand f(a)(b). Can anyone please tell me how to read f(a)(b) or how is this resulting to a type of C or please refer me some online material that can explain this to me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/1636/currying/5412/currying#t=201608031429246291326) example probably describes both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if somebody is looking for an explanation. This [link](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala) explains it better

```
def add(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y

add(1, 2)   // 3
add(7, 3)   // 10
```

After currying

```
def add(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x + y

add(1)(2)   // 3
add(7)(3)   // 10
```

In the first sample, the add method takes two parameters and returns the result of adding the two.  The second sample redefines the add method so that it takes only a single Int as a parameter and returns a functional (closure) as a result.  Our driver code then calls this functional, passing the second “parameter”.  This functional computes the value and returns the final result.

Answer (score 5):

Basically the return type of `f(a)` is a function of type `B => C` lets call this result `g`.
If you then call `g(b)` you obtain a value of type `C`.
`f(a)(b)` can be expanded to `f.apply(a).apply(b)`

Answer (score 3):

In the `uncurry` method you take a so-called "curried" function, meaning that instead of having a function that evaluates *n* arguments, you have *n* functions evaluating one argument, each returning a new function until you evaluate the final one.

Currying without a specific support from the language mean you have to do something like this:

```
// curriedSum is a function that takes an integer,
// which returns a function that takes an integer
// and returns the sum of the two
def curriedSum(a: Int): Int => Int = 
   b => a + b
```

Scala however provides further support for currying, allowing you to write this:

```
def curriedSum(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b
```

In both cases, you can partially apply `curriedSum`, getting a function that takes an integer and sums it to the number you passed in originally, like this:

```
val sumTwo: Int => Int = curriedSum(2)
val four = sumTwo(2) // four equals 4
```

Let's go back to your case: as we mentioned, `uncurry` takes a *curried* function and turns it into a regular function, meaning that

```
f(a)(b)
```

can read as: "apply parameter `a` to the function `f`, then take the resulting function and apply the parameter `b` to it".

Comment: Technically `def curriedSum(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b` is not a curried function, it's a method with multiple parameter lists. It's used mostly for type inference, and for _converting_ it to a curried function in a functional context. Just to be accurate.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I guess the OO/FP duality of Scala is the thing that still confuses me the most about the language. :)